# Seleccionar un registro aleatorio de una base de datos MySQL y pasarlo a PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Me gustaría seleccionar un registro aleatorio de una tabla llamada generator1, pero solo si el campo status = 1. Quiero almacenar el campo alt en una variable de php.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora? ¿Nos pasas la tabla con algún dato para poder echarte una mano?

Comment: [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTTu8.png
quiero que seleccione una row aleatoria y que saque alt a una variable pero solo si status es 1  
Gracias :)

Comment: La tabla es gen

Comment: Pásate a este chat y lo comentamos: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90897/radom-row-mysql-php

Comment: Estoy    alli :)  jaja´

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te envío el código PHP que realiza lo que necesitas

```
$conn=new mysqli('localhost','root','','stackoverflow');

$rs=$conn->query("
    SELECT alt FROM generator1 
      WHERE status=1
      ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
");

$r=$rs->fetch_assoc();

$resultado=$r['alt'];

echo $resultado;
```

Así como el SQL que genera la tabla con la que hacer las pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE `generator1` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `alt` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(1) DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO `generator1` (`id`, `alt`, `status`) VALUES
(5, 'test:test1', 1),
(6, 'test:test2', 1),
(7, 'test:test3', 0),
(8, 'test:test4', 1),
(9, 'test:test5', 0);
```

Espero que te resulte útil.

Comment: Gracias  :), funciona

Comment: ¡De nada! Recuerda darle al ok para que salga el tick verde :)